# internal Microphone and Headphones Mutually Exclusive

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones, microphone

When my headphones are plugged into the jack on the side of my laptop (
HP Omen 15-ax250wm) The internal mic is shut off. My laptop is set up to dual boot and this issue does not exist in Windows 10.

I've searched everything I can find on this issue and still came up empty when I tried each suggestion.

I have tried changing the setting with the input/our pins or something of that nature via `hdajackretask` but didn't get very far as it seemed to change nothing. (I know very little about it as it's super technical as far as I can tell.)

I have tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libasound2` `sudo apt-get remove libasound2` and that utterly destroyed my system uninstalling apps left and right.

Why does this functionality work on Windows and not on Ubuntu? It seems as if that blocking of the internal mic on plug in of a headphone jack would be some extra functionality, some setting, some software. (Especially because it works fine on Windows)

Comment: it's not a "functionality" or an "issue" on either system. Neither of these should include preference. and you're talking about preference here, so this classifies this as a "behavior". anyways this is something that is configurable : try installing and running `pavucontrol` and `papref` to see if you can configure both of the inputs to stay on with one of the two tools

Comment: I didn't mean to sound hostile, so please hold back with the gammatude. I've installed pavucontrol again and it's the issue I've had where it assumes my headphones have a mic in them [shown as `microphone (plugged in)`] and it shows my internal mic as `(unplugged)` I've switched to that, but all I get is white-noise for feedback from it. paprefs was almost completely installed, but it gives me this error "(paprefs:5952): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 16:53:44.717: Settings schema 'org.freedesktop.pulseaudio.module-group' is not installed" on running it.

Comment: Somehow my system fixed itself after I played around with `.asoundrc` `/etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf` and a few other threads: (https://pastebin.com/vbGMqtYd)

Comment: it'd be nice to isolate what was the exact fix in he spirit of helping others.

Comment: Had this same issue again. What seemed to help this time was doing a `sudo apt-get autoremove` I can only guess that what causes this issue is having conflicting packages or old software.

Comment: New update, randomly lost sound again and it seems like the way to actually reinstall is to `sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends pulseaudio` then `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` then follow this to add back cookies https://blog.dhampir.no/content/w-pulseaudio-authkey-c-failed-to-open-cookie-file-homeuser-configpulsecookie-no-such-file-or-directory